# Java + Scripting -- Object alteration?

Tags: java

I don't know if the term `Object alteration` is correct here, or if it's even relevant to the question being asked, so I apologise in advice if it's not and **if anyone wants to change the Title feel free**.

Bascially I'm working on a small multiplayer game project in which I want to be able to enable scripting for players to create modifications to their servers without ever touching the original server source code. I'm not sure what scripting language I'm planning on using just yet, but first I need to figure out if this is even possible.

Lets say for demonstration's sake we're using flat-file storage that saves in raw-text format for our players, and our player class looks like this:

```
public final class Player extends AliveEntity {
    private String    name;
    private int       currency;

    public Player(String name, int currency) {
      this.name = name; 
      this.currency = currency;
    }

    // Getters & Setters here...
}
```

Now let's say that our file saving system saves all of the variables in the Player class, so for example our save file may look like this:

```
**JohnDoe.txt**
    name = "JohnDoe"
    currency = 0
```

Lets say that I wanted people to be able to make alterations to the Player class through scripts as part of a modding api which would allow them to add another variable to the class. For example (Psuedo Script Example)

```
**Mod.script**
    Script Start:
        Player.add(Integer, Score)
    :Script End
```

For the sake of the example, lets say that we want this to allow our player class to be something mlike this now, after the execution of the script.

```
public final class Player extends AliveEntity {
    private String    name;
    private int       currency;
    private int       score;

    public Player(String name, int currency) {
      this.name = name; 
      this.currency = currency;
    }

    // Getters & Setters here...
}
```

The score will now be part of the player class and saved in the players file.

Perhaps this implementation idea isn't logical, or is impossible, but I would like to know if it is possible and what the proper way to go about it would be. As you can see I just need to add variables to the player class that can be used by other scripts, and will be saved/loaded with the player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is to have a Map in your player class. This map would not have any types described if you desire to have multiple types.

```
HashMap<Object, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
```

However, if you are to use a scripting language, i believe that typing might be difficult, So you could aswell just stick with Strings.

I would recommend LUA as its quite mature and has good bindings for Java.

Otherwise, you could have a Map with a Object called lets say **Properties**

```
public class Properties{
    String type;
    String value
}
```

You could then use the type property of this object to determine which type it should be when its transfered to the script.

Comment: Thought about this, `Map<String, PluginVariable>` then in the script
`put("variableName", new PluginVariable<Integer>(1));`

Comment: Sounds like a  good solution. Recompiling is not somthing you want to do :). But remember that the scripting language will most likely not have any ways to communicate which type the value is.

Comment: Arne - I was thinking about something like `Groovy` or `Groovy++` (Depricated, now `Groovy 2 Beta`) which I've used in the past which allows variable typing.

Answer (score 1):

Whel you would have to implement some sort of interpreter first (to understand your txt and convert it to java code), it should follow some syntax syntax.

Then you can use a library like [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/) to compile at runtime your new code. With it you can even allow your player to implement directly from java code instead of text to be interpreted.

I would recommend you to create default interfaces and obligate the player to implement it, so your game will have control over whatever the player creates.

I think I don't need to show any code here it is enough explanation. Take a look at the BeanShell library I use to say that it can do black #@$% voodoo magic¨.